# UML relationship owners

Tags: class, uml, associations, relationship

I noticed that in many cases when using UML it is required to know the so called "owner of the relationship". I also know that under a set of associations there are also e.g. directed associations. But I wonder why the common associations are so often used, if they do not allow to determine the owner of the relationship? From what I've seen the owner of the relationship can only determine the directed association, for example:

[image: Car ----> Passenger]

So a Car can have Passengers. My understanding is that Car has access to some passengers, but Passenger does not have access to Car.

However, I have to admit that I rarely see Directed Association in use, most often it's just Association (although I've encountered opinions that Associations themselves are rarely used, but that's rather untrue) - but is it possible to determine the owner of the relationship using just associations? Is it possible only after selecting the direction of association?